# Robertson-Walker metric exercise

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, cosmology, metric-tensor, coordinate-systems

I'm trying to solve an exercise from my astrophysics and cosmology class, the request is the following, starting from the RW metric expression:

$$ \begin{equation*}
ds^2=c^2 dt^2 - a^2 \left ( \frac{dr^2}{1-kr^2} + r^2 (d{\theta} ^2 + \sin^2{\theta}\, d\phi^2) \right )
\end{equation*} $$

I have to find his expression in Cartesian coordinates but I'm stuck when I start consider values of  $ k= 1, -1 $, for $ k=0 $ I took the spherical coordinates and I inverted them to find the expression of the differential of $ dr , d{\theta}, d{\phi} $  in function of the Cartesian ones.

But after this I got stuck, I also have a doubt on the meaning of the variable $ r $ which I found on the internet is defined as the comoving distance, so I thought is the spatial distance of my points when I am in comoving reference frame but I'm not sure about this because on my book the value of $ r $ goes from 0 to 1 when $ k=1 $ and I find that pretty confusing.

Basically I have a lot of doubts about this metric, so  I thank anyone who will share some of his windsom

Please be kind it's my first astrophysics course this exercise is a bit out of my league since I still have to take a General Relativity course, and this course is supposed to be an introduction to the topic

Also at the end of the exercise he gives us a hint which states "try to apply a change of variables using these two expressions": $\sin(\sqrt k r) $  and $\tan (\frac{\sqrt k r}{2} ) $.